# Как вывести сообщение на экран, пока что-то пишется в файл?

Tags: c++, консоль

Задача такая: происходит циклическая обработка символьных данных, есть два открытых файла - один на чтение другой на запись. При определенном условии нужно вывести сообщение пользователю не прерывая работы программы. Вот код, где не работает вывод:

```
freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

for (i = 0; i <= rest; i++) {
    cout << "-";        // пишем в файл
    if (ab >= 1)
        cout << "0" << cj;    // пишем в файл
    else
        printf("вариант ", i, " c ошибкой");    // пишем на экран (не работает)
    cout << "-";        // пишем в файл
}

fclose(stdout);
```

Так наверно понятней будет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если от пользователя не ожидается ответ, то просто:

```
while(...) //
{
 if (условие)
 {
   cout<<сообщение;
 }
}
```

Работа программы не прервется, просто отработает if и выполнение пойдет дальше.

Если от пользователя ожидается ответ, то запустить в отдельном потоке:

```
while(...) // цикл обработки
{
  if (условие)
  {
    Запустить_поток(функция_печати_сообщения);
  }
}

void функция_печати_сообщения()
{
  cout<<информация для пользователя;
}
```

Как запускать поток - это отдельный вопрос. Или средствами API OS, или чем-нибудь кроссплатформенным вроде boost.threads. Так же учтите, что если функция печати сообщения использует какие-то разделяемые данные (shared data), то нужно заблокировать к ним доступ на время работы функции.

Comment: В своем изучении до потоков я пока еще не дошел, если можно поподробнее или хотя бы ссылку где подоходчивей написано.

Comment: @togbit, причем здесь потоки ???

Автор stdout перенаправил (через freopen()) - это раз, и хочет выводить на экран без '\\n', а fflush() не делает - это два.

Ему (автору) надо перед freopen() сохранить stdout например в FILE out (естественно использовав dup() и fdopen()) и выводить на консоль fprintf (out,...); fflush(out)

Comment: @avp: при том, что когда вопрос только был задан, если мне память не изменяет, то кода в нем не было и у меня сложилось впечатление что от пользователя нужен ответ, ожидание которого остановит выполнение.

Comment: Все понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого запись на диск нужно выполнять в другом потоке (thread) =) А главный использовать для информирования пользователя и получения его распоряжений.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, как уже писали выше, ошибка в вызове функции `printf`.
Во-вторых даже вызвав функцию `printf` правильно, на экране Вы все равно ничего не увидите, т.к. сами переназначили `stdout` (а `printf` использует именно его) в файл "output.txt"

Answer (score 1):

гораздо проще другую файловую переменную ввести
ofstream fo("output.txt"[, ofstream::out]);
fo<<"пишем в файл";
cout<<"на экран";
fo.close();

Answer (score 0):

Неправильный синтаксис команды printf. Вы должны писать так:  `printf("вариант %d c ошибкой", i);`
UPD: или я чего-то не понял, или что-то ещё, но `cout` выводит на экран. Чтоб вывести в файл я использую `fprintf`.